# Polymorphic inheritance

Tags: java

I have a question about how to define a method from a subclass or a parent class. For example:

```
public class Thought
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Prints a message.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void message()
   {
      System.out.println ("I feel like I'm diagonally parked in a " +
                          "parallel universe.");

      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

And the child class is:

```
public class Advice extends Thought
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Prints a message. This method overrides the parent's version.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void message()
   {
      System.out.println ("Warning: Dates in calendar are closer " +
                          "than they appear.");

      System.out.println();

      super.message();  // explicitly invokes the parent's version
   }
}
```

If I wanted to invoke method message from the main method, would I have to use `Thought.message`, or `Advice.message` since I used the super invoker. Does super.(method)() technically just copy and paste the parent method into the child method, allowing you to create an object of only the child?

Comment: the `message()` function isnt static, so you'll first have to create an object. then invoke `message()` from that object. The `message()` called will depend on type of the object. Also, `super` passes the control the parent class, not copy it.

Comment: Where is your code of calling method?

Comment: "allowing you to create an object of only the child" - every instance of a child is also an instance of its parents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depend on how you initialize your objects. You can use both. But using polymorphism you could do something like this:

```
Thought t = new Advice();
t.message();
```

And without polymorphism:

```
Advice a = new Advice();
a.message();
```

Since it is `Advice` that inherits the method `message()` from `Thought` and actually invokes a call to its super-class, both methods will be invoked with both examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go back and study OO a bit more...

Yes you can create an object just of the child, but it still `isA` instance of the parent too.

`super.method()` calls the superclass method. It does not copy the superclass method into the subclass.

The superclass implementation of a method might use private variables in that the subclass doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thought t1 = new Thought();
t1.message(); // invokes Thought#message()

Thought t2 = new Advice();
t2.message(); // invokes Advice#message()

Advice a1 = new Advice();
a1.message(); // invokes Advice#message()

Advice a1 = new Thought();  //COMPILATION ERROR
```

As you are calling *instance methods*, at runtime whatever the object you have in the reference will be executed.